# Стоит ли создавать проект на версии Release Candidate Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Стоит ли устанавливать Visual Studio 2012 RC и до выхода финальной версии создавать проекты на ней с помощью ASP.NET MVC 4 или лучше пока использовать Visual Studio 2010 и ASP.NET MVC 3?

Comment: Установил вчера VS2012, убил интерфейс - тупо чёрный шрифт на сплошном сером фоне без обрамления, визуализации кнопок, меню и т.п.

Comment: @Mikola Не знаю, что вас там убило, но у `2012RC` лучший `UI` из всей линейки `Visual Studio`.

Comment: De gustibus non est disputandum, но на UI вот это:  
http://www.easyfoto.ru/20120629212346960.png   
явно не тянет. Или у меня что-то не то с UI ? В настройках среды есть только цветовая тема "Свет" (серое убожество) и "Тёмный" (который вообще для глаз противен)

Answer (score 5):

В отличие от [@andreycha](/users/106/andreycha) я придерживаюсь строго обратной концепции, а именно разумной консервативности. Поясню что я имею ввиду под этим: например, я всегда использую для продакшна версию продукта/компилятора/SDK/API на ступень ниже новейшей.

- Java 6 вместо Java 7
- ANT 1.7 вместо ANT 1.8
- VS 2010 вместо VS 2012
- Android 2.3 вместо Android ICS (Honeycomb 3.Х - отдельная тупиковая планшетная ветвь!)
- и т.д.

Продакшн это не то место где надо экспериментировать с нервами юзеров!

Пробовать другое дело: пожалуйста, но когда дело касается баблосов - шутки и эксперименты в сторону!

**P.S.**

Кстати, [Google в Android использует до сих пор Java 6](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) и это правильно!

Comment: Имейте в виду, что поддержка Java 6 скоро закончится и Java 7 будет основной линией. И да, Java 7 работает уже существенно лучше. Ещё пол года и можно не бояться, а приниматься за тестирование для чего-нибудь серьёзного.

Comment: Насчет продакшна полностью согласен. Только о нем в вопросе ни слова не было :).

Answer (score 0):

Никаких проблем быть не должно. Новая Студия, в отличие от предыдущих, не прописывает свою версию в sln файл, поэтому открыть вы его сможете и в более старых версиях Студии.

Я бы лучше переформулировал вопрос так: использовать ASP.NET MVC 3 или ASP.NET MVC 4? Тут уже зависит от того, что вам нужно.